# UISplitView: detail view is not visible

Tags: cocoa-touch, rotation, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

In `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` I'm adding a split view:

```
[self.window addSubview:splitViewController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

`splitViewController` comes from NIB loaded in app delegate, and is pretty simple one, with table view on the left, and some custom view on the right.

In `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` of `splitViewController` I'm returning NO if interfaceOrientation is either `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` or `UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown`(it makes more sense in my up to show up like this only during the 1st run).

When I run my app in the simulator (SDK 4.2), simulator is rotating to the landscape orientation as I expect, but detail view is not visible (is black). Table view on the left is just fine.

What's interesting, when I rotate simulator 2 times left or right, the **detail view** turns visible as expected.

It seems that at the beginning the **detail view** is behind some other view, I checked it by logging each view controllers' frame (in `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`):

```
Details VC frame: {{0, 20}, {768, 1004}}
SiteSelection frame: {{0, 20}, {768, 1004}}
SPLIT VC frame: {{0, 20}, {768, 1004}}
```

Also, split view controller subviews gives:

```
v: <UIView: 0x5c32d60; frame = (0 20; 768 1004); layer = <CALayer: 0x5c335e0>>
v: <UILayoutContainerView: 0x5c94dc0; frame = (0 0; 768 1004); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x5c94e10>>
```

So it seems that for some reason table view is taking whole iPad's window frame, and is overlapping with detail custom view.

Is that correct? What could be the reason behind that? In NIB everything seems fine. I suspect that `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` is to blame. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess what... Running exactly the same code under Xcode4 works just fine.
So it's unclear to me what is wrong under Xcode3.x, or more likely, iOS Simulator.

Comment: Did you ever revisit this problem? I am having the exact same issue intermittently on an iPad running iOS 4.2, but not on devices running 4.3. A device reboot fixes the problem. It's pretty odd...